# Range Triggers - Salary of Employess

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have a table I called `FUNC` where all my employees are and I have another table where I am able to register different Job Roles... Each Employee must have a Job Role.

My Job Role table has its ID, the name of the role, the minimum wage of the Role and the maximum wage of the Role.

I want to create a trigger that *CHECKS* every time that I give a *RAISE* to some employee if the raise is inside the range of "Minimum Wage and Maximum Wage".

To make it easier to understand I'll show what I've done so far...

```
CREATE TABLE FUNC(
    IDFUNC INT IDENTITY,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SALARY MONEY NOT NULL,
    ID_JOB INT,
    IDGESTOR INT
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE JOB(
    IDJOB INT IDENTITY,
    NAMEJOB VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
    MINIMUM MONEY NOT NULL,
    MAXIMUM MONEY NOT NULL,
)

/* CONSTRAINTS*/

ALTER TABLE FUNC ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC
PRIMARY KEY(IDFUNC)
GO

ALTER TABLE JOB ADD CONSTRAINT PK_JOB
PRIMARY KEY(IDJOB)
GO

ALTER TABLE FUNC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_GESTOR
FOREIGN KEY(IDGESTOR) REFERENCES FUNC(IDFUNC)
GO

ALTER TABLE FUNC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FUNC_JOB
FOREIGN KEY(ID_JOB) REFERENCES JOB(IDJOB)
GO
```

Fed the Tables with those Values:

```
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('MANAGER',5000,10000)
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('SUPERVISOR',4000,7000)
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('LEADER',2000,5000)
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('ANALYST',1200,4000)
GO

IDJOB       NAMEJOB    MINIMUM               MAXIMUM
----------- ---------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           MANAGER    5000,00               10000,00
2           SUPERVISOR 4000,00               7000,00
3           LEADER     2000,00               5000,00
4           ANALYST    1200,00               4000,00
```

//

```
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name1',7000,1,NULL)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name2',5000,2,1)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name3',5000,2,1)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name4',3000,3,2)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name5',3400,3,2)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name6',2800,3,3)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name7',3200,3,3)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name8',2000,4,4)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name9',1800,4,4)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name10',1500,4,5)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name11',1300,4,5)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name12',3000,4,6)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name13',2000,4,6)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name14',1900,4,7)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name15',2100,4,7)
GO

IDFUNC         NAME                           SALARY               ID_JOB      IDGESTOR
------------- ------------------------------ --------------------- ----------- -----------
1             Name1                          7000,00               1           NULL
2             Name2                          5000,00               2           1
3             Name3                          5000,00               2           1
4             Name4                          3000,00               3           2
5             Name5                          3400,00               3           2
6             Name6                          2800,00               3           3
7             Name7                          3200,00               3           3
8             Name8                          2000,00               4           4
9             Name9                          1800,00               4           4
10            Name10                         1500,00               4           5
11            Name11                         1300,00               4           5
12            Name12                         3000,00               4           6
13            Name13                         2000,00               4           6
14            Name14                         1900,00               4           7
15            Name15                         2100,00               4           7
```

Finally created this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Salary
ON FUNC
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE
    @MINIMUM MONEY, @MAXIMUM MONEY, @SALARY MONEY, @IDCARGO INT

    SELECT @IDJOB = IDJOB FROM JOB
    INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON IDJOB = I.ID_JOB
    WHERE IDFUNC = I.IDFUNC

    SELECT @MINIMUM = MINIMUM, @MAXIMUM = MAXIMUM
    FROM JOB WHERE IDJOB = @IDJOB

    SELECT @SALARY = I.SALARY FROM INSERTED I

    IF(@SALARY <@MINIMUM)
    BEGIN

        RAISERROR ('Salary Must be Higher than Minimum',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    IF(@SALARY > @MAXIMUM)
    BEGIN

        RAISERROR ('SALARIO Must Be Lower than Maximum',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
GO
```

It works fine when I update just one row....

EX:

```
UPDATE FUNC SET SALARY = 15000 WHERE IDFUNC = 1
GO
```

It will show an error, because my Employee which IDFUNC=1 should receive between 5000 and 10000 SINCE HE is a Manager

My problem is when I try to update all my rows at once...

Like if I wanted to give a raise for everybody

```
UPDATE FUNC SET SALARY = SALARY*1.1
```

The update function does not check for the conditions inside my trigger and updates the salary regardless if it is inside or outside my range....

Comment: `INSERTED` has multiple rows - your code is selecting only 1 random `@IDJOB` - you need to handle `inserted` using a set based approach.

Comment: Do you have any links explaining how to use "Based Approach" so I understand it?

Comment: Everything SQL should be using a "set based approach" - there are loads of links e.g. [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-set-based-vs-procedural-programming-approaches-t-sql/)

Comment: From the design/operation perspective having triggers that "partially" succeed is a **nightmare**. Triggers are meant to enforce data constraints, as opposed to perform user input validation. I hope the subtle difference is clear.

Comment: If you need to perform this validation in SQL, then I suggest you write an SP or a function that can check this for each employee and display relevant errors **before** you do the update.

Comment: I agree with Alex (I've run out of comment votes) - allowing a partial update at this level will cause all sorts of issues..

Comment: Agree with Alex too (and I have comment votes left!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `inserted` contains multiple rows. Unlike most other databases, SQL Server does not support *per row*  triggers (that is implemented using the `for each row` clause).

You need to check all inserted rows at once, and reject them all if any fails the check. Here is an approach using conditional aggregation:

```
create trigger trg_salary
on func
for insert, update
as
    declare @isfailed int

    select @isfailed = max(
        case when i.salary not between j.minimum and j.maximum 
            then 1 
            else 0 
        end
    )
    from inserted i
    inner join job j on j.idjob = i.idjob

    if(@isfailed = 1)
    begin
        raiserror ('salary must be belong to the minimum-maximum range',16,1)
        rollback transaction
    end

go
```

Comment: Table JOB does not have the column IDFUNC
"inner join job j on j.idfunc = i.idfunc"

Comment: @marceloasr your question states ` WHERE IDFUNC = I.IDFUNC` - even though your table doesn't define it. People tend to assume your posted code is correct!

Comment: Yes, but that's because Table FUNC has the Column IDFUNC, Table JOB does not...

Comment: But you wouldn't write `WHERE IDFUNC = I.IDFUNC` in that case, because thats the same as writing `1 = 1` if they are both in the same table? Anyway check my answer.

Comment: @marceloasr: ok si I guess you want the join on `idjob`. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now it Works fine.... The problem is I thought it would have a way to UPDATE part of the employees SALARY... Doing Row By Row...

Comment: Did not understand this part.... When I'm doing this:  
"case when i.salary not between j.minimum and j.maximum "

I'm testing ROW BY ROW if I.SALARY is between Minimum and Maximum or I'm testing just one time?

Comment: @marceloasr: this is conditional aggregation: the operation is performed on each row, and then `max()` is applied. So if any record has a salary outside the range, you get `1` as a result.

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERTED` pseudo-table contains 0-N rows, where N is the number of rows being inserted/updated (and can be zero!). Because of that, and because SQL is optimised for "set based operations" you need to build a query to test your error condition.

However because of that, unless you want to return a list of errors, you can only return 1 error even if multiple exist.

Also its best practice to use `THROW` rather than `RAISERROR`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Salary ON FUNC
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ERROR NVARCHAR(2048);

    SELECT TOP 1 @ERROR = CASE WHEN I.SALARY > MAXIMUM THEN 'SALARIO Must Be Lower than Maximum.' WHEN I.SALARY < MAXIMUM THEN 'SALARIO Must Be Higher than Minimum.' END
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN JOB J on J.IDJOB = I.ID_JOB
    WHERE I.SALARY > MAXIMUM OR I.SALARY < MAXIMUM;

    IF @ERROR IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        THROW 51000, @ERROR, 1;  
    END;
END
GO
```

Comment: It works... But it does not update the Salary of the employees that is inside the range.., I'd like to Update the Salary that are able to be updated and return error for the others... Is it possible?

Comment: @marceloasr thats not what your question asks... in fact its a radically different question with a very different answer.

Comment: @marceloasr and how will your UI cope with a partial update? Won't that be confusing to your users?

Comment: @marceloasr I suggest researching `INSTEAD OF` triggers.

Comment: User input validation in triggers is a terrible, terrible idea. Triggers are meant to enforce data constraints. Write a function or an SP instead.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d2fc/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE FUNC(
    IDFUNC INT IDENTITY,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SALARY MONEY NOT NULL,
    ID_JOB INT,
    IDGESTOR INT
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE JOB(
    IDJOB INT IDENTITY,
    NAMEJOB VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
    MINIMUM MONEY NOT NULL,
    MAXIMUM MONEY NOT NULL,
)

/* CONSTRAINTS*/

ALTER TABLE FUNC ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC
PRIMARY KEY(IDFUNC)
GO

ALTER TABLE JOB ADD CONSTRAINT PK_JOB
PRIMARY KEY(IDJOB)
GO

ALTER TABLE FUNC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_GESTOR
FOREIGN KEY(IDGESTOR) REFERENCES FUNC(IDFUNC)
GO

ALTER TABLE FUNC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FUNC_JOB
FOREIGN KEY(ID_JOB) REFERENCES JOB(IDJOB)
GO

INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('MANAGER',5000,10000)
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('SUPERVISOR',4000,7000)
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('LEADER',2000,5000)
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('ANALYST',1200,4000)
GO
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name1',7000,1,NULL)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name2',5000,2,1)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name3',5000,2,1)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name4',3000,3,2)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name5',3400,3,2)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name6',2800,3,3)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name7',3200,3,3)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name8',2000,4,4)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name9',1800,4,4)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name10',1500,4,5)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name11',1300,4,5)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name12',3000,4,6)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name13',2000,4,6)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name14',1900,4,7)
INSERT INTO FUNC VALUES('Name15',2100,4,7)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Salary
ON FUNC
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM JOB J
        INNER JOIN INSERTED F
        ON J.IDJOB = F.ID_JOB
        WHERE F.Salary < J.Minimum OR F.Salary > J.Minimum
    )    
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('SALARIO Must Be Lower than Maximum and Greater than Minimum',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
GO
```

**Query 1**:

```
--UPDATE FUNC SET SALARY = 15000 WHERE IDFUNC = 1

UPDATE FUNC SET SALARY = SALARY*1.1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d2fc/2/0)**:
SALARIO Must Be Lower than Maximum and Greater than Minimum